# How to get aggregation class properties of a Elasticsearch NEST response?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

When running this:

```
searchResponse = _elasticClient.Search<Assets>(s => s
                .Aggregations(a => a
                    .Filter("myFilter", f => f
                        .Filter(fi => fi
                            .Bool(b => b
                                .Must(
                                    m => m.Term(t => t.TitleType, type),
                                    m => m.Term(t => t.Categories, category))))
                        .Aggregations(aggs => aggs
                            .Terms("myUnique", te => te
                                .Field(f1 => f1.Genres))))));
```

I get this as a response:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 50751,
    "max_score" : 0.0,
    "hits" : [ ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "myFilter" : {
      "doc_count" : 50281,
      "myUnique" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "Other",
            "doc_count" : 9879
          },
          {
            "key" : "Anime",
            "doc_count" : 5948
          },
          {
            "key" : "Reality",
            "doc_count" : 4354
          },
          {
            "key" : "Drama",
            "doc_count" : 3333
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is exactly what I want. However, I don't know how to access the class properties in the response. I would think something like this would work:

```
agg = searchResponse.Aggregations.Terms("myFilter.myUnique"); // Does not work!
```

I would like to get all the "keys" found in the aggregated response found above, e.g. Drama, Reality etc.

My goal is to run this after the line above:

```
foreach (var genre in agg.Buckets)
                {
                    var value = genre.Key;
                    var count = genre.DocCount;

                    DoSomething(value, count);

                }
```

I am sure there is a way, but can't find any examples on the web. Has anyone done something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was totally missing a few important lines in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/filter-aggregation-usage.html):

```cs
var filterAgg = searchResponse.Aggregations.Filter("myFilter");

var terms = filterAgg.Terms("myUnique");
```

and then I can do:

```cs
foreach (var genre in terms.Buckets)
{
    var value = genre.Key;
    var count = genre.DocCount;

    DoSomething(value, count);
}
```